# How do I write text in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to understand ColdFusion, as I am coming from ASP.NET.  I've put together a sample page to piggy-back off some already finished code -- but I can't seem to get the actual data from the object I am creating:

```
<cfset objProduct = createObject("component", "com.MyObj.Product")>
<cfset prodExists = objProduct.getProduct(10)>
<html>
<head/>
<body>
<h2>#objProduct.ProductName#</h2>
</body>
```

... It simply prints the literal #objProduct.ProductName# text, and not the data from within the object.  Any idea where I'm going astray?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't forget the `<cfoutput>`!

```
<cfoutput>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>#HtmlEditFormat(objProduct.ProductName)#</h2>
  </body>
</html>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Also, dont forget `HTMLEditFormat()`. It's the one and only reason that XSS attacks even exist - people constantly forget to HTML-escape their output. So... this should be `#HTMLEditFormat(objProduct.ProductName)#`, actually.

Comment: @tomalak I'd like to know more about your specific information on HTMLEditFormat() and why it should be used. Can you provide a link to the specific information that makes outputting text without this tag such a horrible idea?

Comment: @Evik: The reason is very simple. It prevents creating buggy HTML by accident and it prevents cross-site-scripting (XSS) attacks. Some info on XSS and why it is dangerous would be here, for example: http://www.cgisecurity.com/xss-faq.html. Many other resources exist, just search for them.

Comment: [`HtmlEditFormat` (ColdFusion 9) documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7847.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. You forgot the CFOUTPUT tags.
2. You're trying to output the wrong variable.

   #objProduct.getProduct(10)#

or

```
<cfoutput>#prodExists#</cfoutput>
```